# How can I prevent enemies from going through doors aboard my ship?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

Is there any way to stop boarded enemies from being able to open my ship's doors? I currently have not found any means of 'trapping' them.

Comment: On a side node, level 3 doors are usually sufficient to suffocate your enemies while cracking at max one door. Level 2 will usually allow them to break up to three doors before suffocating and Level 1 will not resist in any way. They will however try to flee to a secure room when running out of oxygen, so be prepared.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Upgrading your Doors subsystem will improve your doors to Blast Doors, which slow down the spread of fire and require enemies to break them open before they can pass through; a higher level means they can contain fire and enemies even better. In Advanced mode, you can temporarily upgrade the subsystem by having a member of your crew man the Doors control panel on your ship.

Additionally,

> You can use a Crystal crewmember's Lockdown ability to block all doors to the room the crewmember is in for a limited period of time.

Comment: @AeolianBard You can also open doors by clicking on them. This is useful when you trap boarders in a room with an external door >:D

Comment: I think this is only for FTL advanced, I don't think the base game has many of these features.

Comment: @coteyr The bit about manning the Doors system is indeed only in the Advanced mode, I'll make a note about it.

Comment: @acbabis Indeed. One standard strategem among my friends is to Vent the air in rooms that crew members never need to get to (on larger ships) so that enemies will suffocate quickly. It is also sometimes possibly to herd fire towards enemies and suffocate both at the same time. Enemies will often follow open doors, so it is also sometimes possible to trick them into getting into fights with your crew in your medbay.

Comment: One additional point that may be worth mentioning is that if your door subsystem is hacked, those doors will prevent your crewmembers' movement and will allow the passage of your foes instead.